# Sqlite Python Database Structure problem How can I fix it?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite table and I want fix this problem. I 'm a computer engnieer student and my lecturer give this project this project is gets inventory levels of product on amazon.

So, this:

```
| Tarih      | DB'Store | BO'Store| Famex Sports|
-------------------------------------------------
| 07.11.2019 |    NULL  |  NULL   |     NULL   |
|    NULL    |    3     |  NULL   |     NULl   |
|    NULL    |    NULL  |  9      |     NULL   |
|    NULL    |    NULL  |  NULL   |     NULL   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Should become this:

```
| Tarih      | DB'Store | BO'Store| Famex Sports|
-------------------------------------------------
| 07.11.2019 |    3     |  9      |     NULL   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

isim is string /
sonstok is integer

I added full of my code ı need help for this situatio. This program gets inventory levels of the product of on amazon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do in your Python script, but here is a SQLite query which would generate the output you expect:

```
SELECT
    MAX(Tarih) AS Tarih,
    MAX("DB'Store") AS "DB'Store",
    MAX("BO'Store") AS "BO'Store",
    MAX("Famex Sports") AS "Fame Sports"
FROM yourTable;
```